# How to search multiple keywords in web page? this only input one keyword

Tags: python

import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import smtplib

## True by default

while True:

```
url = "https://www.google.com"
browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.open(url)
response = browser.response().read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "lxml")
count = 1
if str(soup).find("English") == -1:
    # wait 60 seconds (change the time(in seconds) as you wish),
    print('Checking - ' + str(count) + 'th Time')
    time.sleep(60)
    count += 1
    # continue with the script
    continue
```

Comment: this can only search "English" keyword i want to add more keywords

Comment: search with multiple words, if that words appears in the website i need to get alert

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of problems here:

1. Beautiful soup provide a method [`get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) to extract the text, so you do not need to convert it to string.
2. String's [`find()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) return `-1` when *no value was found*. Are you sure that is what you want?
3. Why do you use `time.sleep()`? What is the purpose of stopping the program?
4. You did not create a loop, which make `count` redundant and you will get error for [`continue`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops).
5. If you want to get the number of occurence of a string, you can use [`regex's findall()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp#findall) and then get its length like: `len(re.findall("English", soup_text))`.
6. If you want to find multiple keywords, you can create a list of the keywords and then loop through them like:

   ```
   for k in ["a", "b", "c"]:
       print(f'{k}: {len(re.findall(k, soup.get_text()))}')
   ```

Full example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests  # simple http request
import re  # regex

url = "https://www.google.com"
doc = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(doc.text, "lxml")
soup_text = soup.get_text()
keywords = ["Google", "English", "a"]
for k in keywords:
    print(f'{k}: {len(re.findall(k, soup_text))}')
```

You are strongly suggested to study python thoroughly:

- Python: [w3school tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_intro.asp)
- BeautifulSoup: [Documentation](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- Regex: [w3schools tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp) or [RegExr](https://regexr.com/)